# Flutter Android App do Not Receives a Response

Tags: android, flutter, dart, post, https

I'm using http.post to get data from a https address hosted on Hostgator shared server.

A PHP script is receiving the data. I could confirm that by writing everything on a log.
Also, PHP is responding, because I have logged the answer too. And the script is terminating correctly.

However, the App remais stuck in the await http.post and **do not return the response** from the server.

With android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" the server does not receive anything. I'm using android:usesCleartextTraffic="false".

If the script is hosted by a computer on the same network (using http on my LAN), everything works fine.
The problem starts when I switch to call an external https.
However, when calling `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/` the response comes. Of course it is not the data expected by he App. But it reaches the D2 below.

```dart
print("D1"); //<-- this is printed
var map = Map<String, dynamic>();
    map['username'] = user;
    map['password'] = pass;
    map['nottoken'] = token;

    var response = await http.post(url, body: map);

print("D2"); //<-- this is never printed. The app stay stuck on screen
```

On the https (Hostgator shared) server I logged:

```
THE PARAMS FROM THE APP
Array
(
    [username] => master
    [password] => ******* <omitted>
    [nottoken] => <omitted>
)

THE RESPONSE FROM THE SERVER
{"status":true,"data":{"id":"1","email":"leandro.israel.p@gmail.com","username":"master","password":"<omitted>","profile_id":"12","name":"Master User","clients_ids":"","timezoneutc":"0","timezonestr":"America\/Sao_Paulo","lastreadnot":"2024-02-09 23:48:28","departamentos_ids":"","regdate":"2017-06-26 13:02:30","validemail":"1","accesscode":"20240210154314","nottoken":"<ommitted>"},"msg":""}
----- END ----
```

MY ATTEMPTS

- I have changed to another shared host without success. Maybe there are some security policies.
- Have used http on the server without success
- The https URL works on Insomnia
- Have tried Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*" on .htaccess and with PHP header(...). Also Access-Control-Allow-Methods with GET, POST.
- I have made an script to receive the App requisition, call the desired https by curl and print the data for the App. **It works great**. But I have hosted this script in my local network. Maybe I will have to find a public server just to host this script.

Comment: Have you tried to set a time-out as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/q/60648984/150978 ?